# Evaluating gradient at a certain point

Tags: matlab

Consider the following code:

```
syms x y z
f = 2*y*z*sin(x) + 3*x*sin(z)*cos(y);
gradf = gradient(f, [x, y, z]);
```

What I'd like to do is to evaluate `gradf` at a certain point `(x,y,z)`.

How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: did my answer not work? Would you prefer a more detailed explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [subs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/use-subs-to-evaluate-expressions-and-functions.html).

```
x=1; y=1; z=1;
subs(gradf)
```